# Partial derivative of a composite function $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: derivatives, differential-topology

I am trying to understand a proof but I am stuck on this technical bit:

[image]

Apart from the small typo highlighted, I don't really see how to get the big formula for the partial derivative of $v_i$

What I keep getting is the following:

$$\partial_i v_i(x)=\displaystyle \sum_{j,k=1}^{n}  d_{i,j}(x) \partial_k (w_j(f(x))\partial_i( f_k) +\sum_{j=1}^n w_j(f(x)\partial_i d_{i,j} $$

where $\partial_k (w_j(f(x))=\displaystyle \frac{\partial w_j(f(x))}{\partial f_k}$

Later in the book an expression very similar to the one I get appears...are they the same thing? Is there a huge typo?

**EDIT**: I am thinking it could be that $W\not = w$ for some reason, is it a standard notation for something I don't know? I don't really see why they would have changed to capital letters otherwise...

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Did you also apply $\partial_i$ to the $d_{i,j}(x)$-Term?

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 ah yeah you're right I forgot the second part!

Comment: And in the first sum, it should be $d_{i,j}(x)$ and not $d_{j,k}$, and it should be put at the end in order not to confuse the reader.

Comment: @user10676 are you talking about the bit I copied from the book? I think it's wrong as well..

Comment: For me too, the book is wrong. I may be misunderstanding the notations. However the typo is very bad (writing $divv(x)$ for $\operatorname{div} v(x)$...).

Comment: @user10676 it's very annoying...loads of typos, it makes understanding so much slower!!! Does anyone know another book on this subject (topological degree theory (Brouwer etc.) ?